# Integral Equation Solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking into solving the following integral equation:

$$y(x)=1+\int^{x}_{0}(\tanh s)y(s)ds$$

How can I go about turning this into a differential equation? i.e. of the form

$$y'(x)=f(y)$$ for some function $f$ so we can then apply $y(0)=1$ to deduce a solution by standard techniques for Differential Equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

differentiate both sides using the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus):
$$
F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt\Rightarrow F'(x)=f(x)
$$
$$
y'=y\tanh x
$$
integrate:
$$
\log y=\log\cosh x+C
$$
$$
y=C\cosh x
$$
initial conditions:
$$
y(0)=1=C
$$

Answer (score 3):

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.