# Integral Equation & Picard's Theorem further work

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Following on from my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98512/integral-equation-solution/98517#98517) about the integral equation

$$y(x)=1+\int^{x}_{0}(\tanh s)y(s)ds$$

we now look to appeal to Picard's Theorem.

Let $\{y_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ be the sequence of Picard Approximations for which

$$y_0(x)=1$$

$$y_{n+1}=1+\int^{x}_{0}\tanh(s)y_n(s)ds \quad \quad (n \geq 0)$$

We're asked to prove that

$$y_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} (\log \cosh x)^k$$ and that $y_n \longrightarrow y$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$.

We know the solution $y$ to be the function $y:=\cosh(x)$.

Any help with determining how this works would be very appreciated. Regards and best, as always. MM

Comment: Just iterate putting $y_0(s)=1$ and using the fact that $\int ds\tanh(s)=\log\cosh s+C$.

Comment: @Jon: Don't know how I didn't spot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repeat the comment as an answer being it correct.

Just iterate putting $y_0(s)=1$ and using the fact that $\int ds\tanh(s)=\log\cosh s+C$.